# Laravel validator after method running before the validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I have validation rules in the below

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'ports' => 'required|array|min:2|max:10',
        'ports.*.id' => 'required|distinct|exists:ports,id',
        'ports.*.order' => 'required|distinct|integer|between:1,10',
    ];
}
```

and the withValidator method

```
public function withValidator($validator)
{
    // check does order numbers increasing consecutively
    $validator->after(function ($validator) {
        $orders = Arr::pluck($this->ports, 'order');
        sort($orders);

        foreach ($orders as $key => $order) {
            if ($key === 0) continue;

            if ($orders[$key - 1] + 1 != $order) {
                $validator->errors()->add(
                    "ports.$key.order",
                    __('validation.increase_consecutively', ['attribute' => __('validation.attributes.order')])
                );
            };
        }
    });
}
```

If the client doesn't send the `ports` array, `Arr:pluck` method throwing an exception because of `$this->ports` equal to `NULL`. How can I call this code block after validation completed in formRequest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write in

```
if ($validator->fails())
{
    // Handle errors
}
```

Ex.

```
public function withValidator($validator)
{
  if ($validator->fails())
  {
    $orders = Arr::pluck($this->ports, 'order');
    sort($orders);

    foreach ($orders as $key => $order) {
       if ($key === 0) continue;

       if ($orders[$key - 1] + 1 != $order) {
           $validator->errors()->add(
               "ports.$key.order",
               __('validation.increase_consecutively', ['attribute' => __('validation.attributes.order')])
           );
       };
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `!$validator->fails()` because @akcoban want to run `public function withValidator($validator)` after all rules are passed without errors